# Moments of Transmuted Lindley Distribution

Tags: distributions, moments, integral

I've been having difficulty in obtaining the exact solution given by the author. I need help as my solution doesn't factorize completely to the same term given by the author.

Obtaining the kth moments entails computing the integral given in the picture. I carried out the integration but I did not get the exact term the author got. I was of the opinion that I may be wrong in my factorization, hence I seek other ideas to obtain the exact solution the author got. Otherwise, I want to be justified that the author is probably wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use mark-up to show your workings so far.

Comment: If you can drop email I could send you a pdf file of my workings. Trying to find my way round the mark-up ish though. Thanks.

Comment: I am suggesting what you should do to improve the public question, not volunteering private help. As it stands, this is too difficult to follow.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: The original notation used in the text: $(2\theta + 3 \theta + k)$ suggests a typo .. more likely it was intended to be a quadratic such as $(2\theta^2 + 3 \theta + k)$ ... but in any event, both versions appear to be incorrect,

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it was meant to be quadratic because the mean and other moments corresponds with subsequent values of k.

Answer (score 2):

Focus on the form of the integrand that matches what you can compute.  Specifically, the expectation can be written

$$\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}(X^k) &= A\int_0^\infty x^k(1+x)e^{-\theta x}\left(B + (C+Dx)e^{-\theta x}\right)\mathrm{d}x \\
&=A\int_0^\infty\left((Bx^k + Bx^{k+1})e^{-\theta x} + (Cx^k + (C+D)x^{k+1} + Dx^{k+2})e^{-2\theta x}\right)\mathrm{d}x
}$$

with $A = \theta^2/(1+\theta)$, $B=1-\lambda$, $C=2\lambda$, and $D=2\lambda\theta/(1+\theta)$.

This splits into a sum of five gamma integrals, so we can read off the answer directly: it is
$$A\left(Bk!\theta^{-k-1} + B(k+1)!\theta^{-k-2} + Ck!(2\theta)^{-k-1} + (C+D)(k+1)!(2\theta)^{-k-2} + D(k+2)!(2\theta)^{-k-3}\right).$$

Factor out $\theta^{-k-2}k!$ to obtain

$$\frac{Ak!}{\theta^{k+2}}\left(B(\theta+k+1) + C2^{-k-1}\theta + (C+D)(k+1)2^{-k-2} + D(k+2)(k+1)2^{-k-3}\theta^{-1}\right).$$

The term involving $B$ equals

$$\frac{k!}{\theta^k(1+\theta)}(1-\lambda)(\theta+k+1),$$

recognizable in the first part of the answer.  The other terms equal

$$\frac{k!\lambda}{\theta^k(1+\theta)^2 2^{k+2}}\left(k^2 + (4\theta+5)k + 4(1+\theta)^2\right).$$

That's not remotely like what the author obtained.  Although I, too, may have made some algebraic mistake, it is obvious that some multiple of $k^2$ must be involved, because the original integral includes a multiple of $x^{k+2}e^{-2\theta x}$, which will introduce $(k+2)!=(k^2+3k+2)k!$ upon integration: that $k^2$ cannot be canceled off by any of the other terms.

Comment: Very nice and helpful. I think I have gotten something like this also. Let me try it out to see if the subsequent moments tally with what he got. Thanks a whole bunch @whuber. Please what application did you use in typing these math objects because I seem not to be able to do directly from my keyboard?

Comment: I typed $\TeX$ markup directly.  See the help for "MathJax" when you are editing a question or answer.

Comment: From your result, $$E(x)=\frac{1}{\theta(1+\theta)}[(1-\lambda)(\theta+2)+\frac{\lambda}{\theta(1+\theta)2^3}(1+(4\theta+5)+4(1+\theta)^2)$$ which is different from what he got. I believe the author is wrong sort of.